# Is there a negative impact on runtime of using multiple withColumn( ) functions on the same DataFrame in Pyspark?

Tags: python, pyspark

Let's say that I have a DataFrame called 'a' with some existing attributes/columns: 'col1', 'col2'. My task is to create new columns based on existing and newly created columns. I don't know any other way of doing this other than doing the following (with random numbers as conditions):

```
a = a.withColumn('col3', when(col1 > 2, 5))
a = a.withColumn('col4', when(col3 < 6, 4))
```

My concern is that I have to overwrite 'a' multiple times, because col3 does not exist at the time I would want to use it in a condition for 'col4' for example. So this would just not run:

```
a = a.withColumn('col3', when(col1 > 2, 5))\
     .withColumn('col4', when(col3 < 6, 4))
```

In my task I have a lot of new columns that take another column (which is to be created as well) as a condition. Is this okay to keep redefining my existing DataFrame, or is there a smarter way to go about it?

Comment: the second code sample would run perfectly. each `withColumn` with project the data within the lineage which means you can chain multiple `withColumn` and use the recently created column, without having to overwrite a df. have you tried using the second sample? did you face any challenges? if yes, please share. having said that, your first sample and second sample are same for spark.

Comment: I get an error: 'DataFrame' has no attribute: col3 (or basically the column that is the requirement for the next one)

Comment: you won't be able to use df.col3 but you can reference it using the `col` function. e.g., `func.col('col3')`

Comment: Oh wow..:) Do you know why that is?

Comment: col3 is not a part of df but part of the chain (projection). so df will have no reference of the column, but it can be accessed from the projections.